# Mapping from one union type to another in typescript

Tags: typescript

I've been enjoying union types in typescript, but I've just hit my first snag.

This is the member in question:

```
organizations: Organization[] | number[];
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
let orgs = organziations.map(org => org.id);
```

In other words, take this collection of `<Organization[]>` and map it to its id so that I can have instead a collection of `<number[]>`.

The error I get is **[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature**. True, map doesn't know which of the types it is dealing with. Unfortunately, nothing I've tried thus far has helped map out.

Comment: What should happen if it *is* an array of numbers? `(org: Organisation | number)` inside that map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) in order to test if the variable has the right type. For example:

```
interface Organization {
    id: string
}

function isOrganizationList(list: any[]): list is Organization[] {
    return list.length === 0 || list[0].id !== undefined
}

let organizations: Organization[] | number[],
    orgs: string[];

if (isOrganizationList(organizations))
    orgs = organizations.map(org => org.id);
```

Notice: you could write your own implementation of `isOrganizationList` with a more robust test.